Github Actions: environment String is not fetched

I create PROD environment in Github.



I add Environment secrets as below.



I will fetch these keys with String.fromEnvironment.

class _HomeState extends State<Home> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    const supabaseUrl =
        String.fromEnvironment('envkey_SUPABASE_URL', defaultValue: "check1");
    const supabaseAnonKey = String.fromEnvironment('envkey_SUPABASE_ANONKEY',
        defaultValue: "check2");
    return const Scaffold(
      body: Row(
        children: [
          Column(
            children: [
              Text("check"),
              Text(supabaseUrl),
              Text(supabaseAnonKey),
            ],
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}



I deploy flutter web with Github Actions in .github/workflows/workflow.yml.

I create environment file with SpicyPizza/create-envfile@v2.0.
name: gh-pages

on:
  push:
    branches: [main]
jobs:

  PROD:
      runs-on: ubuntu-latest
      environment: PROD
      steps:
        - uses: actions/checkout@v2
        - name: Create environment file
          uses: SpicyPizza/create-envfile@v2.0
          with:
            envkey_SUPABASE_URL: ${{ secrets.SUPABASE_URL }}
            envkey_SUPABASE_ANONKEY: ${{ secrets.SUPABASE_ANONKEY }}
        - uses: subosito/flutter-action@v1
        - uses: bluefireteam/flutter-gh-pages@v7
          with:
            baseHref: /injicare-event/

Build is done successfully.
However, deployed site shows default value from String.fromEnvironment, which means i can't fetch keys from environment.

I've also added Repository secrets either as below..

I've struggled with this problem for more 2 months.
I've done all as all searched document say, but nothing works..
Please help me..!!!! T_T

Try to cat you .env file to make sure it looks like what you expect:
...
          with:
            envkey_SUPABASE_URL: ${{ secrets.SUPABASE_URL }}
            envkey_SUPABASE_ANONKEY: ${{ secrets.SUPABASE_ANONKEY }}
        - name: Display .env
          run: cat .env
        - uses: subosito/flutter-action@v1
...

Verify your code and read your custom action documentation.
When you pass envkey_MY_VAR, the action will set MY_VAR=value in your env file (doc).
So that code:
String.fromEnvironment('envkey_SUPABASE_URL', defaultValue: "check1");

should be:
String.fromEnvironment('SUPABASE_URL', defaultValue: "check1");

Finally, do you need env files?
Env files are "just" a way to manage environment variables and make your life easier in some cases (local dev, for example). But they are "just" a level of indirection around regular environment variables.
In this workflow, you probably want to use actual environment variables. In Github Actions, simpler is usually better; you might save time by using simpler actions and native GitHub tooling like actions/upload-pages-artifact and actions/deploy-pages.
on:
  push:
    branches: [main]
jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    environment: PROD
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - name: Setup Flutter
        uses: subosito/flutter-action@v1
      - name: Build Flutter Web
        run: |
          flutter config --enable-web
          flutter build web --release --base-href /injicare-event/
        env:
          SUPABASE_URL: ${{ secrets.SUPABASE_URL }}
          SUPABASE_ANONKEY: ${{ secrets.SUPABASE_ANONKEY }}
      - name: Upload Artifacts
        uses: actions/upload-pages-artifact@v3
        with:
          path: build/web/
  deploy:
    needs: build
    permissions:
      pages: write      # to deploy to Pages
      id-token: write   # to verify the deployment originates from an appropriate source
    environment:
      name: github-pages
      url: ${{ steps.deployment.outputs.page_url }}
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Deploy to GitHub Pages
        id: deployment
        uses: actions/deploy-pages@v4

Note that the build part is straightforward; you could run it on your machine. The part that deals with deploying pages is a well-known and documented Github action.
